# conditionals in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, categories

Why this code works fine:

```
<?php if (**is_page**('4')) { ?> 
<style type="text/css"> 
body {background-image:url("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/bac4.jpg");} 
</style> 
<?php } else ?>
```

and this not:

```
<?php if (**is_category**()) { ?> 
<style type="text/css"> 
body {background-image:url("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/coaching.jpg");} 
</style> 
<?php } else ?>
```

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: it should work. is_category() will be true when you're viewing a single category (usually http://example.com/category/)

Comment: Yep that should work just fine. You could remove the else if you're not providing an alternative in the logic.

Comment: can you confirm what is_category() outputs? It's the only thing I can think of that could be causing the issue...

Comment: It's merely a true/false to check whether or not a category page is being displayed: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in my template's header.php. Add some stuff to your template's archive.php, preferably inside the `is_category()`, to verify you're on a category page. Also, I find the alternative if syntax easier to read and debug, but YMMV.

```
if( is_category() ):
    ?>
    <!-- some html -->
    <?php
else:
    ?>
    <!-- other -->
    <?php
endif;
```